# How to publish & Subscribe at server side using SimpleMessagingBroker in Spring

Tags: java, spring, messaging, stomp

I am trying to publish from one class and subscribe from another class using simple messaging broker. Below is the sample code of what i am trying to do.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1500) public void Hello() {
    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/hello",new String("Hello"));  
}

@MessageMapping("/topic/hello") public void HelloWorld(String greet) {
    System.out.println(greet);  
}
```